# Writing an Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

what is the problem with the following code? When i write the same controller without the "shows" and $http element, which is an app.factory, my web site works fine, but not when i add those. $scope.anan is a test element to see if my index.html catches the controller. When i write the controller like this, index.html prints out "{{anan}}"":

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "shows", function($scope, shows) {
    $scope.anan = "boommm";

  shows.success( function(data) {
    $scope.showlar = data;
   } );

} ]);
```

When i write it like this, index.html prints out "boommm":

```
 app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
 $scope.anan="boommm"; 

  }]);
```

and here's the code for shows:

```
 app.factory("shows", ["$http", function($http) {
    return $http.get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/shows-api/shows.json")
    .succes( function(data) {
        return data;
  })
    .error( function(err) {
        return err;
  });


}]);
```

That means index.html is fine, and the mistake is either in controller or in service.

Comment: Uhm assuming it all correct with the controller, here is the directive's code, one of them has to be doing something wrong:

app.directive("tvShow", function() {
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { info: "=" },
    templateUrl: "js/directives/tvShow.html"
  };
});

Comment: Open your console an it will usually give you a warning of what's going wrong.

Comment: where's the code for 'shows'?

Comment: Didn't you mix up controller and module ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .succes( function(data) {
> ```

```
.success(function(data) {
```

---

And also you don't need any `return`s in callbacks, so in your case you don't need callbacks.

Comment: sorry prior code was the wrong one, just edited with my current code.

Problem is, $scope.anan is just for test, in the index.html i currently get" {{ anan }}" when  i run the code. When i chance the controller as this and nothing else:

** app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

        $scope.anan="boommm";
        }]); **

THEN i get "boommm" instead of {{anan}} when i run the code. So the program is either in shows.js service or MainController.js controller.

Comment: @DenizUluğ, you do still have the call to `shows.success` in the controller.

Comment: @DenizUluğ, see the code in your question. Please, update the question so that it contains both working and failing code.

Comment: ok just did, thanks for helping tough this drove me carzy for 2 days.